# How to create tournaments bracket style layout through viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I am trying to integrate tournament bracket in an android app.

Something like following layout.

[image]

I tried creating multiple fragment and assigned them to view pager, but that didn't give me the desired result. I found out a project that is using 1 fragments to make this work.

I need to know if there is some library that can provide tournament brackets layout.

Comment: glad you found out about my project. I just released a library for the same due to overwhelming response. You can find it here https://github.com/Emil333/TournamentBracketLib